# boost::bind doesn't work with pointer argument

Tags: c++, boost-bind

I have this simple program. Here I try to bind member function with object and call later on with arguments required in member function call.
When the member function taken a **pointer to integer**, gcc fails to compile. With integer parameter the program gets compiled. Is this a bug with boost::bind or am I missing something?

```
// Doesn't work with pointer
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

struct X
{
  float f_;
    float& f(int *aa) {
      cout << *aa << endl;
      return f_;
    }
};

int main() {
    X x;

    x.f_=200.1;
    int j = 10;

    cout << bind(&X::f, ref(x), _1)(&j) << endl;    
}
```

---

```
ERROR:
member.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
member.cpp:22: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_bi::bind_t<float&,  boost::_mfi::mf1<float&, X, int*>, boost::_bi::list2<boost::reference_wrapper<X>, boost::arg<1> > >) (int*)’
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:17: note: candidates are: typename boost::_bi::result_traits<R, F>::type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()() [with R = float&, F = boost::_mfi::mf1<float&, X, int*>, L = boost::_bi::list2<boost::reference_wrapper<X>, boost::arg<1> >]
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:23: note:                 typename boost::_bi::result_traits<R, F>::type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()() const [with R = float&, F = boost::_mfi::mf1<float&, X, int*>, L = boost::_bi::list2<boost::reference_wrapper<X>, boost::arg<1> >]
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:29: note:                 typename boost::_bi::result_traits<R, F>::type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(A1&) [with A1 = int*, R = float&, F = boost::_mfi::mf1<float&, X, int*>, L = boost::_bi::list2<boost::reference_wrapper<X>, boost::arg<1> >]
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:35: note:                 typename boost::_bi::result_traits<R, F>::type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(A1&) const [with A1 = int*, R = float&, F = boost::_mfi::mf1<float&, X, int*>, L = boost::_bi::list2<boost::reference_wrapper<X>, boost::arg<1> >]
```

---

```
// Works fine
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

struct X
{
  float f_;
    float& f(int aa) {
      cout << aa << endl;
      return f_;
    }
};

int main() {
    X x;

    x.f_=200.1;
    int j = 10;

    cout << bind(&X::f, ref(x), _1)(j) << endl; 
}
```

Comment: Pointer version works on g++ 4.2.1 (osx)

Comment: What environment are you testing this code under ?

Comment: What version gcc and Boost do you use? I tested both examples with gcc 4.3 and Boost 1.42 and there were no compilation errors.

Comment: The first version compiles for me, albeit with me making minor changes like not putting in "using namespace" and using a function rather than main.

Comment: The pointer version works fine with Boost 1.42, using MinGW g++ 4.4.1 and MSVC 10.0. Which version of Boost are using? And which compiler?

Comment: gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 boost version 1.33.1. OS: RHEL 2.6.18 SMP x86_64. If gcc/boost version is the issue, I will test my example on another system with latest configuration and update you all. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to bind should be the pointer to the object to apply the non-static method to:

```
cout << bind(&X::f, &x, _1)(&j) << endl;
```

Comment: This is equivalent to cout << bind(&X::f, ref(x), _1)(&j) << endl; For more details see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers

Comment: Hmm... you are right. I never used that form. I used the form I provided, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested that the problem code works with boost 1.40 and gcc 4.4.3. I made further changes to test some more scenarios and they all work. The following piece of code **works** perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

struct X
{
  float f_;
  float& f(shared_ptr<int> aa) {
    cout << *aa << endl;
    return f_;
  }
};

struct XX
{
  float f_;
  float& f(int* aa) {
    cout << *aa << endl;
    return f_;
  }
};

struct XXX
{
  float f_;
  float& f(int* aa, int a) {
    cout << *aa << " " << a << endl;
    return f_;
  }
};


int main() {
  X x;
  XX xx;
  XXX xxx;
  xx.f_ = 2000.11;
  xxx.f_ = 20.11;

  shared_ptr<X> p(new X);

  x.f_=200.1;
  p->f_=20000.11;
  int i = 5;
  int j = 10;

  shared_ptr<int> sh(new int(100));
  x.f(sh);
  cout << bind(&X::f, ref(x), _1)(sh) << endl;      // x.f(i)
  cout << bind(&X::f, &x, _1)(sh) << endl;          //(&x)->f(i)
  cout << bind(&X::f, x, _1)(sh) << endl;           // (internal copy of x).f(i)
  cout << bind(&X::f, p, _1)(sh) << endl;           // (internal copy of p)->f(i)

  cout << bind(&XX::f, ref(xx), _1)(&j) << endl;        // x.f(i)
  cout << bind<float&>(mem_fn(&XXX::f), ref(xxx), _1, _2)(&j, i) << endl;       // x.f(i)
}
```